# How to bypass admin right to launch Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: xamarin.android, admin, visual-studio-2022, maui, ms-android-emulator

I am new to MAUI App development. I start a project and try to run the Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2022. But it requires me to enter admin username and password. Currently it's impossible that company IT grants me admin right so I have to find a bypass to run the Android Emulator to debug my code.

Could somebody gives me a hint?

Thank you

Comment: Ask your IT department to set your pc and software up so that it works. Without having to enter any password. They are the only ones who can fix a situation involving Admin access.

Comment: I have the same problem and I used the Android Studio to create the android emulator. So you can download the Android Studio on your PC.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Could you be more explicit about what has to change for that?